# splitting of urls from a list in dataframe where column name is company_urls

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe(df) like this:

```
     company_urls
0   [https://www.linkedin.com/company/gulf-capital...
1   [https://www.linkedin.com/company/gulf-capital...
2   [https://www.linkedin.com/company/fajr-capital...
3   [https://www.linkedin.com/company/goldman-sach...
```

And df.company_urls[0] is

```
['https://www.linkedin.com/company/gulf-capital/about/',
 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/the-abraaj-group/about/',
 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/abu-dhabi-investment-company/about/',
 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/national-bank-of-dubai/about/',
 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/efg-hermes/about/']
```

So I have to create a new columns like this:

```
    company_urls                                          company_url1       company_url2    company_url3 ...                   
0   [https://www.linkedin.com/company/gulf-capital...     https://www.linkedin.com/company/gulf-capital/about/   https://www.linkedin.com/company/the-abraaj-group/about/...
1   [https://www.linkedin.com/company/gulf-capital...     https://www.linkedin.com/company/gulf-capital/about/  https://www.linkedin.com/company/gulf-related/about/...
2   [https://www.linkedin.com/company/fajr-capital...     https://www.linkedin.com/company/fajr-capital/about/...
3   [https://www.linkedin.com/company/goldman-sach...     https://www.linkedin.com/company/goldman-sachs/about/...
```

How do I do that?

Comment: what should the split be based on? On what character?

Comment: the comma(,) is the split character in a list.

Comment: Try the function below and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

I have created this function for my personal use, and I think will work for your needs:
a) Specify the `df` name
b) Specify the `column` you want to `split`
c) Specify the `delimiter`

```
def composition_split(dat,col,divider =','): # set your delimiter here
    """
    splits the column of interest depending on how many delimiters we have
    creates all the columns needed to make the split
    """
    x1 = dat[col].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.count(divider)).max()
    x2 = ["company_url_"+str(i) for i in np.arange(0,x1+1,1)]

    dat[x2] = dat[col].str.split(divider,expand = True)
    
    return dat
```

Basically this will create as many columns needed depending on how you specify the delimiter. For example, if the URL can be split 3 times based on a certain delimiter, it will create 3 new columns.

```
your_new_df = composition_split(df,'col_to_split',',') # for example
```

Comment: As you can see in df.company_urls are separated by , and  \n so I put divider = ', \n' . I'm getting a new column called company_url_0 but the values are NaN

Comment: when you just use , for divider, it does not work?

Comment: Getting this error ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: hmm.. Not sure then.  Can't help a lot if I can't replciate your data